# Unable to sign_up using Devise and CanCan in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I been working on my application in which I have a number of roles and also some users.

However suddenly I can't sign-up anymore. Signing in works fine, but signing up always redirects me back to the signing page and produces the same error:

[image]

The console always shows the following when I try to sign up:

```
Started POST "/registers/user/registration" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-18 00:48:22 +0100
Processing by RegistersController#registration as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"ofucDxxzZFbTVLfVaA3QxixOHL2V9hzxfSFU/99Pd60=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Omar Arroum", "email"=>"omar@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "id"=>"user"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms

Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-18 00:48:22 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (9.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 61.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I haven't made any changes to the `user_controller.rb, so not sure what is causing this issue

EDIT: Added the `RegistersController`

```
class RegistersController < ApplicationController
  #before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET /registers
  # GET /registers.json
  def index
    @registers = Register.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @registers }
    end
  end

  # GET /registers/1
  # GET /registers/1.json
  def show
    @register = Register.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @register }
    end
  end

  # GET /registers/new
  # GET /registers/new.json
  def new
    @register = Register.new(:event_id => params[:event_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @register }
    end
  end

  # GET /registers/1/edit
  def edit
    @register = Register.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /registers
  # POST /registers.json
  def create
    @register = Register.new(params[:register])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @register.save
        format.html { redirect_to @register, notice: 'Register was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @register, status: :created, location: @register }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @register.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /registers/1
  # PUT /registers/1.json
  def update
    @register = Register.find(params[:id])

    StudentRegister.find_all_by_register_id(@register).each do |streg|
      streg.update_attributes(:present => false, :late => false)
      #sets the users status as being absent, mainly for the purpose of when copying a new register,
      #as the presence and lateness is otherwise maintained
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @register.update_attributes(params[:register])
        format.html { redirect_to @register, notice: 'Register was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @register.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /registers/1
  # DELETE /registers/1.json
  def destroy
    @register = Register.find(params[:id])
    @register.students.delete_all_on_destroy
    @register.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to registers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def registration
    @studentregister = StudentRegister.find_all_by_register_id(params[:id])

  end

  def copy
    @register = Register.find(params[:id]).amoeba_dup #Creates a duplicate of the existing register with all Students in it
    @register.date = Date.today #Sets the registers date to today's date
    @register.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to edit_register_path(@register) } #Redirects to the edit page so that they can make any updates
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in your RegistersController (most likely). That is what produces the 401 response and that flash message with Devise. CanCan should have nothing to do with it. Post your RegistersController.

Comment: The strange thing is, why is it trying to use the `RegistersController`? `Register` is my own model, not Devise's one, so not sure why that's happening. I'll update for you to see my `RegisterController`

Comment: You either customized your form to use your own controller, or you have `:controllers => { :registrations => 'registers' }` on your `devise_for` method in routes.rb.

Comment: My `routes.rb` uses the default `devise_for :users resources :users` method. Question is though, why is it trying to access the RegistersController when this is the sign up stage?

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured out what the issue was.

Due to the fact that I had a file called `Registration.html.erb` and an action name `registration` my route looked like this:

```
match 'registers/:id/registration' => 'registers#registration', :as => 'registration'  #Route for taking the register
```

Problem is that Devise uses this action name internally, so my code was being routed wrongly.

To solve this, I changed everything named `registration` to `take_register`, like so:

```
match 'registers/:id/take_register' => 'registers#take_register', :as => 'take_register'  #Route for taking the register
```

That did the trick for me, and now all works